# I am attempting the quick start tutorial and I am at this command "cargo build --release --package node-template-runtime" on this page

Tags: substrate, polkadot

https://docs.substrate.io/quick-start/modify-the-runtime/

and I get this error after it completes a bunch of the build.

the current crate is indistinguishable from one of its dependencies: it has the same crate-name `pallet_grandpa` and was compiled with the same `-C metadata` arguments. This will result in symbol conflicts between the two.
--> runtime/src/lib.rs:9:5

The tutorial wants me to update the chain while it's running, but I am seeing if I can update it after stopping it and then completing the build then restarting the chain. That's doing the tutorial incorrectly, But I'll do that until you guys answer on here. "You guys", the proverbial internet.

Comment: Even shutting down chain first gives same error

Answer (score 0):

you have to change this line in file substrate-node-template/runtime/Cargo.toml

"sp-core = { version = "7.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.42" }"

all you have to change is version from 7.0.0 to 7.0.0-dev